# Using functions in SQL Server to do string manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a number of stored procedures that will need to perform string manipulation on a column in a table.

Can I create a function to do the string manipulation and call it from the SP? If yes, how would I do that?

Example:

I have a table named 'Names' and it it has one column named 'DocName'

My SP would look like:

```
select DocName, MyStrFunc(DocName) as NewName
FROM Names
```

MyStrFunc would adjust the passed value and return a string.

We will have many SPs that will need to use MyStrFunc and do not want to duplicate the string manipulation code.

Comment: please read https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/ and close your question.

Comment: I believe that your current question can be summarized as "can I create a user-defined function in SQL Server?" To which the answer is [yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx), as even cursory research will tell you. If you want to know how to perform a specific string operation, then please first [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx), try to find a solution yourself, and post here if you get stuck.

Comment: No that is not the question. I do know that UDF can be created. All examples I found do much more than simple string manipulation, i.e. they return subsets of tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example with a [user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StringConverter 
(
    @oldValue varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(100)
    -- do your custom manipulation here. this is just an example
    SELECT @Result = upper(@oldValue)
    RETURN @Result
END
GO

-- and to use it
SELECT x.a as src, dbo.StringConverter(x.a) as converted
FROM (
   SELECT 'asdf' as a
   ) as  x

-- results
src   converted
asdf  ASDF
```

Answer (score 3):

What you'll want is a scalar-valued function.  To create one of these, go to your Object Explorer in SSMS, open the database, open the Programmability folder, then the Functions folder.  Right-mouse-button-click on Scalar-Valued Functions folder and click "New Scalar-value function".

This will give you the shell of what you need to create the function.  Then you should be able to call that function from anywhere.

*Your scalar-value function will need to take a varchar or nvarchar as input--not a column name.*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have dynamic column names in SQL.

The only way to achieve this is to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), which comes with its own dangers ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) being the foremost of which).